# SolrCloud - Parent shard cannot be deleted after shard splitting

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I performed shard splitting on 2 of the shards out of 3 with the async request id.
The shard splitting task is failed when it trying to attach the replica for the splitted shard, but i found out on both of the leader splitted shards, document is splitted correctly (total numFound of both shards = total numFound of parent shard)

So, i proceed to manually change the clusterstate.json, splitted shards changed status from construction to active, and parent shards changed from active to inactive. I also manually attach the replica for the splitted shards, then only remove the parent shards by unload the parent shards core.

Here the problems come, when i issue a commit in SolrCloud, both of the parent return back in the solr cloud cloud graph and clusterstate.json with node status = down & shard status = active.

1)  I bring up the parent shards node again and try with another unload core again, but every time i issue a commit, it will back into the graph and clusterstate with node status = down & shard status = active.

2) So my second attempt is to delete the shards with collection API using */admin/collections?action=DELETESHARD*

I got the error as below :

> org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException:Cannot >unload non-existent core
>
> Operation deleteshard caused exception:
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not fully remove collection: >candidates shard: candidates_shard2 at 
>   org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:364) at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:320) at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleDeleteShardAction(CollectionsHandler.java:563) at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:176) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:729) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:267) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:612) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AutoLoginValve.invoke(AutoLoginValve.java:67) at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:304) at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:82) at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

3) My third attempt is the delete the replica using the collection API *admin/collections?action=DELETEREPLICA*

I got the error as below :

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not remove replica
>
> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not remove replica : candidates/candidates_shard2/core_node48 at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:364) at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:320) at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRemoveReplica(CollectionsHandler.java:495) at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:184) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:729) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:267) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:207) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:612) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AutoLoginValve.invoke(AutoLoginValve.java:67) at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:304) at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:82) at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

How should i remove that 2 unwanted parent shard from the cluster?